# CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False. while debug is true

Tags: python, django, docker, environment-variables

in the settings.py i use environs for my debug and in docker-compose.yml i set it to True
my django is 4.2.4
and python 3.11.3
settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path

# from django.db.models import Q
from environs import Env

#
# from accounts.models import CustomUser
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.

env = Env()
env.read_env()
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env.bool('DJANGO_DEBUG')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - 'DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=...'
      - 'DJANGO_DEBUG=True'
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
```

but it says CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS  if DEBUG is False

i try asking chat gpt and its help and internet and in manage .py i import a file and in that i add django.setup and settings.configure after this i have this error

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/ are you sure you are getting env as True ?

Comment: yes ahitsham im sure

Comment: I mean as bool `True` check its type by printing it before assigning to `DEBUG`

Comment: yes i even try it without enviorment variables

Comment: can any one help me